# Prevent Firefox from saving addresses on specific website

Tags: firefox, autosave

As of Firefox v63, under Preferences > Privacy & Security > Forms & Passwords there is a button called "Saved Addresses..." which contains any name and address information that was previously entered into a form.

With this in mind, my question is if there is a way to prevent Firefox from automatically adding into Saved Addresses the names / addresses entered into a form from one or many websites while still saving addresses working on all other websites?

Also, I am aware there is a way to remove addresses from the Saved Addresses, what I am looking for is a way to prevent them from being added in the first place from one website.

Comment: Firefox typically asks you whether you want to save the entered information at the time you enter it.  But you're looking for a web site "blacklisting" provision for anything that might be automatically saved?  Have you verified that the current version is actually saving anything automatically?

Comment: At least from my experience, all addresses I have entered into forms are being automatically saved into the Saved Addresses listing without any prompt given beforehand.

Comment: I'm not aware of a native provision to blacklist saving with that kind of granularity, but I'm looking forward to any answers you might get to the contrary.